# Deriving expression for lengths of line segments drawn from point to a parabola along a given line

Tags: analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

> A line which makes an acute angle $\theta$ with the positive direction of $x$-axis is drawn through $P(3,4)$ to cut the curve $y^2=4x$ at $Q$ and $R$. Show that the lengths of the segments $PQ$ and $PR$ are numerical values of the roots of the equation $r^2\sin^2\theta+4r(2\sin\theta-\cos\theta)+4=0$.

Here is what I have done so far. Consider the parametric form of the line $x_{1}=3-r\cos\theta$ and $y_{1}=4-r\sin\theta$. I have affixed a $-$ sign to account for the fact that $(3,4)$ lies outside the parabola. Now all that is required is that $(x_{1},y_{1})$ lies on the parabola. Putting this into the equation of the parabola gives $r^2\sin^2\theta-4r(2\sin\theta-\cos\theta)+4=0$.

I am getting a $-$ sign in the required equation. Why is that? What if a point was inside the parabola, would we have affixed a $-$ sign to $r$ in writing the parametric form? Thanks.

Comment: I believe your answer is better, although these answers only differ by the sign of $r$; for $2 \sin \theta > \cos \theta$, the equation given by the question will produce two negative values of $r$. However there is no solution for $r$ if $\tan \theta < 1$, and for $\tan \theta \ge 1$, we must have $2 \sin \theta > \cos \theta$, so the equation given by the question *always* give negative values of $r$, which does not make sense.

Comment: @player3236 Thanks for clarifying.